# Using jQuery, taking an element to display

Tags: jquery, html, css

The first to thank everyone for helping me. Sorry for my english is bad :)

I need jquery, can get the name of the tab is selected and displayed in the `h1`. Selected tab changes, the `h1` change over.

Ex, I have :

```
  <div class="header-inner">
      <div class="cal-menu-na">
        <h1>Text Here</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <span class="sone active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="one">One ABC</a></span>
      <span class="stwo"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="two">Two XYZ</a></span>
      <span class="sthree"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="three">Three QWE</a></span>
      <span class="sfour"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="four">Four FGH</a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="main-contain">
      <div class="tabContainer">
        <div id="one" class="Tabcondent active">Tab One</div>
        <div id="two" class="Tabcondent">Tab Two</div>
        <div id="three" class="Tabcondent">Tab Three</div>
        <div id="four" class="Tabcondent">Tab Four</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And I want:

```
  <div class="header-inner">
      <div class="cal-menu-na">
        <h1>One ABC ( or Two XYZ or Three QWE or Four FGH )</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <span class="sone active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="one">One ABC</a></span>
      <span class="stwo"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="two">Two XYZ</a></span>
      <span class="sthree"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="three">Three QWE</a></span>
      <span class="sfour"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab="four">Four FGH</a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="main-contain">
      <div class="tabContainer">
        <div id="one" class="Tabcondent active">Tab One</div>
        <div id="two" class="Tabcondent">Tab Two</div>
        <div id="three" class="Tabcondent">Tab Three</div>
        <div id="four" class="Tabcondent">Tab Four</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

FULL DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/zh8rqnkd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the text of selected `a` and update the text of `h1` using `.text()` on the click event :

```
$('.cal-menu-na h1').text($(this).text());
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zh8rqnkd/2/)**

Answer (score 4):

Use it to set the `text` of clicked tab to that `h1` element,

```
$(this).closest(".navbar").prev(".header-inner").find("h1").text($(this).text());
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zh8rqnkd/1/)

---

- `closest` will get the first matched parent element based on supplied
  selector.
- `prev` will get the immediate previous sibling and it will ignore
  text nodes.
- `find` will get the descendants matches the supplied selector.

The above code will help you to set the text when you have the same kind of html structure more than once. But if you have the given html structure only once, then you can simply use it `$("div.header-inner > .cal-menu-na > h1").text($(this).text())` to acheive what you want.